# Android- Storing Large files at compile time

Tags: android, storage, compile-time

How exactly does one go about such a simple thing in this beautifully over-complicated framework?

Yes I've read the documentation on Data Storage for Android, about 54.5 times. But I can not find anyplace where the documentation describes how you should go about placing files on the external storage at compile time.

Here's what I want to do: I want to include a couple of (big) (10-20mb) audio files in my application. Naturally, I do not want these to be stored on the internal storage, because they're just too big. So placing them in res/raw is not an option (because, if I understand correctly, things in res/raw will be placed in the internal storage of the phone, correct?)

The documentation only states that "if you want to store static files at compile time, use res/raw". Now if Android is smart enough to place those files on the external storage all by itself then I'm forever greatful.. But somehow I doubt that. All help is appreciated :)
(Sorry if it seems like I have an attitude, I've just spent way too much time on something so simple)

Thanks again :)

UPDATE: I ended up downloading the files from the application instead of including them at install-time. Thanks for the help guys!

I hit a problem while trying to download through a url, spent a lot of time trying to get it to work, and in the end the problem was because I hadn't declared the correct permission in the android manifest file! So to anyone who's looking to download stuff in their apps, do not forget to set the permissions in the android manifest, here are the permissions I needed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Place these above the start of the  tag

Comment: What API level are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your large files are in the APK, they'll be stored wherever the APK gets stored - this can be internal or external, and it seems that this is not what you want. The most likely option for you seems to be to place the files on a web site and during the first run of your application, it must notice that the files do not exist and retrieve them post-installation.

Comment: Ah, ok... Thanks for the advice. Do you have a tip on how to detect "first-run"?.. Or should I just crudely check if the file exists every time?

Comment: You've already solved this, but in response to your question I would have advised checking if the file exists every time -- doing this allows you to deal in the event that the user has replaced their external storage where another method (such as using 'SharedPrefs') would not.

Answer (score 0):

> how you should go about placing files on the external storage ***at compile time***.

I'm assuming the above is a typo and you mean ***at install time***.

As for your requirement - it's not possible to instruct the Android Application Manager to unpack different parts of an APK to different places during the installation.

Further to this, there's no guarantee that an APK download will go to the internal or external memory storage (where it will stay unless otherwise deleted).

And even further to this, there's no guarantee that even if a device has external storage, it will be available at installation time or have enough free space.

At this point I wonder about audio files which are 10-20MB in size - either they're very long (in duration) or they're encoded at a high bit-rate. If it's the latter then this doesn't make too much sense as most mobile devices have fairly poor audio reproduction (in relative terms)....just some thoughts to mull over.

I personally think mah's suggestion of downloading post-installation may be a better approach but my comments about availability of external storage still hold true.

Comment: yeah, they're long. I've managed to lower the bitrate so they're at 4-5 mb now.. still, include a couple of these and you're allready up on 20-30 mbs, so the question still stands. :)

Answer (score 0):

Proper approach to solving your problem on Android is "don't put them with your application". Just download them on first start from your web server (using HTTP client API) or, if these files will be upgraded independently of the application itself, prepare them as a separate "application" for the user to download via Market.

Comment: Thanks for the http client API tip, I'll definitely look into it!